# dates in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a textbox for a date value which I retrieve as

```
Dim myDate as string = txtDate.Text.Trim
```

the value is in a `dd/MM/yyyy` format. e.g. 16/02/2012
of course for single digits, this could also be 1/2/2012

I have, in my web.config;

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"/>
```

Then I use,

```
Dim newDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(adate, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)
```

which produces `"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."` error

I have also tried the following with no luck!:

a)

```
Dim newDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(adate, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing)
```

b)

```
Dim format() = {"dd/MM/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy"}
Dim newDate as Date = Date.ParseExact("16/02/2012", format, nothing)
```

for this specific one, I also tried specifiying culture-specific format information and formatting style instead of `nothing` above..

Any ideas? I have run out of mine....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
Convert.ToDateTime("28/02/2012", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-gb"))
```

Please let me know if it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your example dates, you're using the `.` character as the separator. In your code, you're using `/`.

Make sure you consistent and see if that takes care of things.

Comment: Actually I have no "." (dots) in my code. I typed it here by mistake. So you can assume I do not use dots..

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Dim myDate as DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("28/02/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"))

myDate.ToShortDateString()
```

Obviously you can massage that code to fit your needs.

Comment: @Emin: this is what I was using as an example.  Is there something that can help [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4690/parse-a-uk-date-string/)